# Manually trigger syncing of SharePoint online groups from AD

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, active-directory, active-directory-import

Is there a way to sync the groups from AD to SharePoint online manually?

It usually takes around a day for the newly created groups to appear in O365 and I am not able to find any way to sync them immediately as and when AD groups are created

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new group in AD how long does it take to show up in Azure AD?  Azure AD connect should be syncing your local AD to Azure AD on a schedule, typically every 30 minutes.  Once the group shows up in Azure AD it should be available to SharePoint Online.  If everything is working properly new groups should show up after 30 minutes max, you might need to look at your Azure AD Connect server to make sure it is syncing correctly and is not getting sync errors.

Comment: groups usually appears only the next day. From what I have seen, group syncing seem to happen only during the night. They appear in Azure AD in 30 minutes, but in SP online, it only shows up the next day

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a timer job that sync user profile to SharePoint, and in SharePoint Online, it's not supported to run this timer job manually, I recommend you wait the sync to complete automatically.

Comment: can we configure when it runs? like have it run thrice a day